# How to list sub folder of section on hugo

Tags: hugo, hugo-content-organization, hugo-theme

How to list the subfolders of sections on an HTML page in Hugo for now I use the list.html file of the section

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use {{ .Pages }} to list all RegularPages and all list pages (direct children). However, if you are looking for a nested menu partial, take a look at this one:

https://hugocodex.org/add-ons/nested-menu/